# I have a ListView populated adata from SQLite. I am trying to add an onClickListener to each row to pass it to the next activity

Tags: javascript, android, arrays, listview, android-arrayadapter

I am a bit stuck I want to be able to pass the selected row  and display it in another activity...

I have the following code that queries the database and fills the listview, but I can't find the way to pass the information to another activity. Any help?

ListViewActivity to display data from SQLite database

```
   public class ListViewActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
   ListView listView;
    ArrayList<Shoe> list;
    ListViewAdapter adapter = null;
    ImageButton cart;

    public static SQLiteHelper sqLiteHelper;

    ImageView imageView;
    TextView name,price;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.list_activity);

        cart = findViewById(R.id.imageButton2);

        name = findViewById(R.id.product_name_text);
        price = findViewById(R.id.product_price_textView);
        imageView = findViewById(R.id.Product_imageView);

        sqLiteHelper = new SQLiteHelper(this, "FoodDB.sqlite", null, 1);


        listView= findViewById(R.id.list1);
        list = new ArrayList<>();
        adapter = new ListViewAdapter(this, R.layout.display_home_list, list);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        // get all data from sqlite
        Cursor cursor = sqLiteHelper.getData("SELECT * FROM FOOD");

        list.clear();
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            int id = cursor.getInt(0);
            String name = cursor.getString(1);
            String price = cursor.getString(2);
            byte[] image = cursor.getBlob(3);

            list.add(new Shoe(name, price, image, id));


        }
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();



        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {


               Intent intent = new Intent(ListViewActivity.this,CartActivity.class);

               startActivity(intent);

                
           


            }
        });

            

    }

}
```

these is listview adapter
public class ListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

```
private final Context context;
private final int layout;
private final ArrayList<Shoe> shoesList;




public ListViewAdapter(Context context, int layout, ArrayList<Shoe> shoesList) {
    this.context = context;
    this.layout = layout;
    this.shoesList = shoesList;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return shoesList.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return shoesList.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

private class ViewHolder  {
    ImageView imageView;
    TextView txtName, txtPrice;

}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {


    View row = view;
    ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();

    if (row == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        row = inflater.inflate(layout, null);

        holder.txtName = row.findViewById(R.id.product_name_text);
        holder.txtPrice = row.findViewById(R.id.product_price_textView);
        holder.imageView = row.findViewById(R.id.Product_imageView);


        row.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) row.getTag();
    }

    Shoe shoe = shoesList.get(position);

    holder.txtName.setText(shoe.getName());
    holder.txtPrice.setText(shoe.getPrice());

    byte[] shoeImage = shoe.getImage();
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(shoeImage, 0, shoeImage.length);
    holder.imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

    return row;
}
```

}

Comment: Well what is the problem exactly?

Comment: i don't know how to pass the the selected products in a listView to display them in another array......

Comment: Ok. But what is the problem exactly? Getting the right data,? Or passing data to a new activity? You know you can use putExtra() on the used intent to pass data to the new activity?

Comment: So the user selects what you call a Shoe. You know which one?

Answer (score 0):

Please check below code

```
mListview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Shoe clickedObj = (Shoe) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
            Intent intentToDetay = new Intent(this, CartActivity.class);
            intentToDetay.putExtra("name",clickedObj.getName());
            startActivity(intentToDetay);
        }
    });
```